# Как получить значение ключа JSON используя VBA

Tags: json, vba

Есть такой JSON -

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "calendar_integration": "1",
      "country": "",
      "last_login_time": "",
      "u_e_mail_financial": "",
      "source": "",
      "sys_updated_on": "2018-10-24 12:48:35",
      "building": "",
      "web_service_access_only": "false",
      "notification": "2",
      "enable_multifactor_authn": "false",
      "sys_updated_by": "User",
      "sys_created_on": "2018-09-13 13:29:30",
      "sys_domain": {
        "link": "url",
        "value": "global"
      },
      "state": "",
      "vip": "false",
      "sys_created_by": "admin",
      "zip": "",
      "home_phone": "",
      "time_format": "",
      "last_login": "",
      "active": "false",
      "sys_domain_path": "/",
      "u_address_for_sending_documents": "",
      "cost_center": "",
      "phone": "",
      "name": "USer",
      "employee_number": "",
      "password_needs_reset": "false",
      "gender": "",
      "city": "",
      "failed_attempts": "",
      "user_name": "user@user.com",
      "title": "",
      "sys_class_name": "sys_user",
      "sys_id": "0bef8c99f9e863008ff068a048a5d18f",
      "u_additional_company": "",
      "internal_integration_user": "false",
      "ldap_server": "",
      "mobile_phone": "+7(999)999-99-99",
      "street": "",
      "compan\r\ny": {
        "link": "url"
      },
      "department": "",
      "first_name": "user",
      "email": "user@user.com",
      "introduction": "",
      "preferred_language": "",
      "manager": "",
      "u_current_duty": "false",
      "locked_out": "true",
      "sys_mod_count": "2",
      "last_name": "user",
      "photo": "",
      "u_comment": "user",
      "middle_name": "user÷",
      "sys_tags": "",
      "time_zone": "",
      "schedule": "",
      "u_import_id": "76",
      "u_email_signature": "",
      "u_available": "24/7",
      "date_format": "",
      "location": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Из этого JSON необходимо получить две константы -

Первая - значение ключа `"sys_id"`, а то есть константа будет равна `"0bef8c99f9e863008ff068a048a5d18f"`
Вторая - значение ключа `"compan\r\ny" {"link": }:`. Будет равна `"url"`

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6627652/4928642